# Subsonic: Is it possible to use the oledb provider

Tags: subsonic

When I set up a connection for Subsonic 3.0.0.4 to connect to an Oledb sql provider using the T4 Templates I get the following error: Keyword not supported 'provider' Can Subsonic access a database using OleDb? If so. How?

Answer (score 0):

Which dbms do you want to use?

Since SubSonic 3 uses System.Data.Common for accessing data, it should be possible to use it with every dbms that supports ADO.net (I belive there is a OleDbProvider for ado).

But if you use a DBMS that is not supported by subsonic you have write your own DataProvider and an OleDb.ttinclude template file.

The beste starting point is to look at an existing provider:

https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/tree/master/SubSonic.Core/DataProviders/MySQL
https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master/TemplateProviders

Creating your own Provider shouldn't be to hard at all. I would use a Copy&Paste approach from an existing provider and modify everything that causes some errors.

Comment: "Shouldn't be hard" - The folks working on Oracle support have certainly encountered challenges, and the SQL generation will also have to be addressed.

Comment: Ok, I admit that it's not done in one afternoon (but if I look at the MySql specific code, the most difficult part is getting the scheme from the database). And, as Snotly mentioned afterwards, the underlying db is a Sql Server 2005, there shouldn't be to much difference in the generated sql.

Comment: Hopefully the fact that the OLEDB is connecting to Sql Server will ease the pain, but despite the apparently small amount of code for, say, MySQL the few devs working on Oracle support have been at it for months, still somewhat unsuccessfully as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the standard SQL to LINQ Entity spaces but I have to connect to a database for a client through their application server's specific OLEDB provider. Apparently it's doing extra work after the standard OLEDB SQL commands are sent to the server. So LINQ as far as I understand is out. I built my own CRUD classes, but it's a pain doing it this way. I just want a tool that can build the standard classed so I don't have to create the layer myself.

It's MS SQL Server 2005 on the other end.